# How to make different layout.php files and include into different languages?

Tags: php, layout

I'm interested in solving this problem, since I can't figure out what to do. I made a fade in/out text under menu for mobile version to show some information, but since the code has to be between two HR lines I added the code to layout.php file, and now I can't put that on 3 other languages because it's on German.

```
<div class="">
   <div class="">
      <hr class="" />
      <div class="" style="">
         <div class="">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
         </div>
      </div>
      <hr class="" style="" />
   </div>
</div>
```

This is the code for that fade In/Out effect and changing from one to another, I managed to do that with nth-child selector, nothing hard...

My web site has 4 languages, but every language has 2 web sites that are different. I'm not using any framework just bare code. I've tried searching for anything that would be connected to that HR line so I could add manually on every site another line and that text between them, but there is none because it uses `layout.php` to show that line.

```
<div id="" class="">
<? if ($special_fullscreen != true): ?>
<div id='' class="">
</div>
<div class="">
    <div class="">
        <hr class="" style="" />
        <div class="" style="">
            <div class="">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="" style="" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="">
    <div class="">
    </div>
</div>
```

So, I would like to hear an idea that would resolve this issue, like making a different layout.php for every language or something like that and how would that be possible. I know that this code probably doesn't have anything to do with the problem, but I'm in a hurry and just tried to copy at least something... Thanks in advance :D

Comment: an api that translates the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am completely not sure if I know what you mean but it may be helpful info.
If you want to include different files on the same page depended on language - you can set cookie with info about chosen language and then, based on that, load proper layout.php file for it.

You can also make all language versions in one layout.php file, include it in proper place and make if statement checking which content should get displayed (inside that layout.php file) - also based on value of COOKIE.

Instead of cookie, you can also use $_SESSION but that may not work on the way you really want (according to my understanding of your problem).

Comment: Alright, and what would be the code for cookie? If thats not a problem, thank you.

Comment: @asobak There is documentation for setting cookies:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Every time that user chooses different language, set some shortcut for it as a value of cookie.
When user visits the page, check if cookie has value (that means user is NOT first time visiting the page) and serve proper content or redirect based on chosen option.

If user visits page for the first time, set default settings for that and then save cookie for him.